# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass. Как исправить?

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь встроить плагин Wordpress в тему Wordpress. Но получаюсь Notice:

**Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$publish in /nas/wp/www/cluster-1664/brandivodemo/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/includes/leads/classes/class.dashboard.php on line 187**

И такое ощущение, что PHP не работает после Notice... Как его исправить? Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Строка 187:** *$all_time_leads = $count_posts->publish;*

```
public static function display_lead_report_widget()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts('wp-lead');
        $url = site_url();

        $c_month    = date( 'n' ) == 1 ? 12 : date( 'n' ); // GETS INT from EDD
        $previous_month = date( 'n' ) == 1 ? 12 : date( 'n' ) - 1; // GETS INT from EDD
        $previous_year  = $previous_month == 12 ? date( 'Y' ) - 1 : date( 'Y' ); // Gets INT year val

        $start_current = date("Y-m-01"); // start of current month
        $end_current = date("Y-m-t",strtotime('last day of this month')); // end of current month

        //getting the previous month

        $previous_month_start = date("Y-m-01", strtotime("previous month"));
        $previous_month_end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 month"));

        $this_month = self::count_leads_by_time( $start_current, $end_current);
        $last_month = self::count_leads_by_time( $previous_month_start, $previous_month_end);

        $all_time_leads = $count_posts->publish;
        $all_lead_text = ($all_time_leads == 1) ? "Lead" : "Leads";
        $leads_today = Leads_Dashboard::get_lead_count_from_today('wp-lead');
        $leads_today_text = ($leads_today == 1) ? "Lead" : "Leads";
        $month_comparasion = $this_month - $last_month;

        if ($month_comparasion < 0)
        {
            $month_class = 'negative-leads';
            $sign = "";
            $sign_text = "decrease";
        } elseif($month_comparasion === 0) {
            $month_class= 'no-change';
            $sign = "";
            $sign_text = "No Change ";
        } else {
            $month_class = 'positive-leads';
            $sign = "+";
            $sign_text = "increase";
        }
        echo '<div id="lead-before-dashboard">';
        do_action('wp_lead_before_dashboard');
        echo "</div>";

        $clean_dates = date("m", strtotime("first day of previous month") );
        $clean_date_two = date("m");
        ?>

        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/plugins/lead-dashboard-widgets/js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

        <div class="wp_leads_dashboard_widget">

        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        window.data1 = [ <?php echo self::get_lead_graph_data( $clean_date_two, 'this-month'); ?> ];
        window.data2 = [ <?php echo self::get_lead_graph_data( $clean_dates, 'last-month'); ?> ];
        /* ]]> */
        </script>
            <div id="flot-placeholder" style='width: 100%; height: 250px; margin: 10px auto 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; margin-bottom:10px;'></div>

            <div id="wp-leads-stat-boxes">
            <div class='wp-leads-today'>
                <a class="data-block widget-block" alt='Click to View Todays Leads' href="<?php echo $url . "/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wp-lead&current_date";?>">
                    <section>
                        <?php echo $leads_today; ?>
                        <br><?php echo $leads_today_text;?>
                        <br><strong><?php _e('Today' , 'leads'); ?></strong>
                    </section>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='wp-leads-this-month'>
                <a class="data-block widget-block" alt='Click to View This Months Leads' href="<?php echo $url . "/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wp-lead&current_month";?>">
                    <section>
                        <?php echo $this_month; ?>
                        <br><?php echo $all_lead_text;?>
                        <br><strong><?php _e('This Month' , 'leads'); ?></strong>
                    </section>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='wp-leads-all-time'>
                <a class="data-block widget-block" title='Click to View All Leads' href="<?php echo $url . "/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wp-lead";?>">
                    <section>
                        <?php echo $all_time_leads;?>
                        <br><?php _e('Leads' , 'leads'); ?>
                        <strong><?php _e('All Time' , 'leads'); ?></strong>
                    </section>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="wp-leads-change-box" style="text-align: center;">
                <small class='<?php echo $month_class; ?>'><?php echo "<span>" . $sign . $month_comparasion . "</span> " . $sign_text;?> <?php _e('Since Last Month' , 'leads'); ?></small>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- <div class='wp-leads-last-month'>
            last month: <?php echo $last_month; ?>

            <?php echo $this_month - $last_month;   ?>
            </div>  -->
            <div id='leads-list'>
            <?php   $r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
                'posts_per_page' => 20,
                'post_type' => 'wp-lead',
                'post_status' => 'publish') ) );

            if ($r->have_posts()) : ?>
            <h4 class='marketing-widget-header'>Latest Leads<span class="toggle-lead-list">-</span></h4>
            <ul id='lead-ul'>
            <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
                <li><?php $id = get_the_ID();
                $first_name = get_post_meta( $id , 'wpleads_first_name',true );
                $last_name = get_post_meta( $id , 'wpleads_last_name', true );
                $name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
                if ($name === " ") {
                    $name = get_the_title( $id );
                }
                ?>

                    <?php edit_post_link($name);?> on <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> (<?php the_title();?>)
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите, что возвращает:

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('wp-lead');
```

Comment: @WP Panda почему-то возвращает пустой объект..

Comment: @eprivalov1 очевидно потому что нет таких постов

Comment: @Etki В БД есть такие посты!

Comment: А почему он должен возвращать не пустой